# How to transfer an image over http

Tags: c#, http, tcp, proxy, httpwebresponse

I am trying to create a proxy, text based requests get processed(js, css, html) properly. But when i try to load in an image i get the message that the image contains errors.

I have tried multiple ways to send this over http but none of them have worked yet. Here is the relevant code

```
 try
        {
            StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
            HttpWebRequest clientRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)clientRequest.GetResponse();
            string headers = response.Headers.ToString();
            string contentType = response.Headers.Get("content-type");
            var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
            if (contentType.IndexOf("image") > -1)
            {
                using (BinaryReader stream = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var bytes = new byte[1024];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var n = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        if (n == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        responseString.Append(bytes);
                    }
                    return "HTTP/1.1 200 \n" + headers + responseString.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                {

                    return "HTTP/1.1 200 \n" + headers + reader.ReadToEnd();
                } 
            }
        catch
        {
            addToList("Request failed");
            return "Request failed";
        }
    }
```

If possible i would prefer to keep the http response string so that I send it over the already existing NetworkStream.

Comment: Just looking at your code and the documentation, I'd suggest that ASCII is not the right encoding as images might contain characters outside of the normal ASCII character set. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The ASCII encoding is only used for the text based requests, i have used none for the images. Unless maybe ASCII is a default

Comment: Is there a reason you are reading the stream the way you are rather than use Image.FromStream()? Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: The reason I'm doing that is because Images aren't the only thing that will need to be processed. Also streaming for example, so I feel like the error is more so in the way that I'm processing/converting the data and not that it's image specific.

Also I'm not getting an error in code. the error is on the webpage saying that the image can't be displayed because it contains errors

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to stream the response directly to the client and not convert it to a string first. The headers are sent in a string before.